# Visual Studio 2010 (C++): suppress C4706 warning temporarily

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

When you compile the following C++ source file in Visual Studio 2010 with warning level /W4 enabled

```
#include <cstdio>  // for printf
#include <cstring> // for strcmp

char str0[] = "Hello";
char str1[] = "World";

int main()
{
    int result;

    if (result = strcmp(str0, str1)) // line 11
    {
        printf("Strings are different\n");
    }
}
```

you get the following warning

> warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression

for line 11.

I want to suppress this warning exactly at this place. So I tried Google and found this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(v=VS.100).aspx

So I changed the code to the following - hoping this would solve the problem:

```
#include <cstdio>  // for printf
#include <cstring> // for strcmp

char str0[] = "Hello";
char str1[] = "World";

int main()
{
    int result;

#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4706)
    if (result = strcmp(str0, str1))
#pragma warning(pop)
    {
        printf("Strings are different\n");
    }
}
```

It didn't help.

This variant didn't help either:

```
#include <cstdio>  // for printf
#include <cstring> // for strcmp

char str0[] = "Hello";
char str1[] = "World";

int main()
{
    int result;

#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4706)
    if (result = strcmp(str0, str1))
    {
#pragma warning(pop)
        printf("Strings are different\n");
    }
}
```

To avoid one further inquiry: I cleaned the solution before each compilation. So this is probably not the fault.

So in conclusion: how do I suppress the C4706 exactly at this place?

**Edit** Yes, rewriting is possible - but I really want to know why the way I try to suppress the warning (that is documented officially on MSDN) doesn't work - where is the mistake?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In MSDN Libray: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(v=VS.100).aspx, There is the section as follows.

> For warning numbers in the range 4700-4999, which are the ones
>   associated with code generation, the state of the warning in effect
>   when the compiler encounters the open curly brace of a function will
>   be in effect for the rest of the function. Using the warning pragma in
>   the function to change the state of a warning that has a number larger
>   than 4699 will only take effect after the end of the function. The
>   following example shows the correct placement of warning pragmas to
>   disable a code-generation warning message, and then to restore it.

So '#pragma warning' only works for an each function/method.

Please see the following code for more detail.

```
#include <cstdio>  // for printf
#include <cstring> // for strcmp

char str0[] = "Hello";
char str1[] = "World";

#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning( disable : 4706 )
void func()
{
    int result;
    if (result = strcmp(str0, str1)) // No warning
    {
        printf("Strings are different\n");
    }
#pragma warning(pop)
}

int main()
{
    int result;

    if (result = strcmp(str0, str1)) // 4706 Warning.
    {
        printf("Strings are different\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Instead of trying to hide your warning, fix [the issue it's complaining about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hw7c1he%28v=vs.80%29.aspx); your assignment has a value (the value on the left side of the assignment) that can be legally used in another expression.

You can fix this by explicitly testing the result of the assignment:

```
if ((result = strcmp(str0, str1)) != 0) 
{
    printf("Strings are different\n");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The sane solution is to rewrite the condition to

```
if( (result = strcmp(str0, str1)) != 0 )
```

which will inform *any* C compiler that you really want to assign, *and* is almost certain to generate the same object code.

Comment: Most compilers implement the "are you sure" factor by requiring an extra pair of brackets, I wish MSVC could do the same.

Answer (score 5):

There is another solution which avoids the warning: the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator#Condition).

The main advantage here will be that you don't need parentheses so it's a bit shorter than the `!=0` solution when your variable name is short.

For example:

```
if (result = strcmp(str0, str1), result) 
{
    printf("Strings are different\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple construction `!!` to cast a type to `bool`. Like this:

```
if (!!(result = strcmp(str0, str1)))
```

However, in some cases direct comparison `!= 0` might be more clear to a reader.