# Nice way to portably "assign within conditional expressions" without warnings (or pragmas)?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I have a piece of code like this:

```
bool finished = false;
size_t offset = 0;
for (Iter i = items.begin();
          i != items.end() || (finished = !finished);
          finished ? i : ++i, ++offset)
{
    do_some_work();
    if (some_condition(other_collection[offset]))
    {
        i = items.insert(i, new_value());
        do_more_work();
        if (blah) { continue; }
    }
    do_more_work();
}
```

The goal is to execute the body for all iterators *including `end()`*.

I get "assignment within conditional expression" warnings from compilers like Visual C++.

#### What's the simplest way to avoid these warnings?

I don't want to turn them off (they're helpful) and I don't want to insert `#pragma`s (they're not portable between compilers).
I just want to write something short that will tell the typical compiler, "yes, I intend to assign here".

The simplest solution I've found is to make a function (e.g. `assign`) and call that instead, but I'm wondering if there is any way that would also avoid defining a new function just for this.

Comment: Note that your `++i` conflicts with your `i = items.insert(...` to some extent -- you will skip an iterator from being visited if you aren't extremely careful.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, it was just an example... don't take it too literally...

Answer (score 5):

Use the good ol' `for i`!

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 5, 23, 2, 44 };
    auto iter = v.begin();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size() + 1; ++i, ++iter) {
        if(iter == v.end()) {
            std::cout << "END!" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

[LIVE CODE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4e8a57b5fdd12d249cb9fc3e8f173f19-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad)

---

**UPDATE:** In response to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306333/nice-way-to-portably-assign-within-conditional-expressions-without-warnings-o/18306422#comment26861732_18306422), I have modified the code to use `std::distance` instead, enabling you to only use iterators without directly knowing the iterator range's size.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


template<typename IterType>
void print(IterType iter /* begin */, IterType end) {
    auto size = std::distance(iter, end);
    for (decltype(size) i = 0; i != size + 1; ++i, ++iter) {
        if(iter == end) {
            std::cout << "END!" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 5, 23, 2, 44 };
    print(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

[LIVE CODE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ceb2ea95b422b11f980be22c57d1b1fa-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad)

Comment: Only works if you know how many items you have to begin with... +1 since it works for most cases, but I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't impose unnecessary restrictions.

Comment: @Mehrdad I know, and I have something to edit to solve that problem. :)

Comment: @mehrdad std::distance is awesome

Comment: @A.H.: Not if it's being called on non-random-access (O(n)) iterators!

Comment: Your loop performs O(n) steps already. (But if you really want an objection, think input iterators)

Comment: Note -- input iterators are probably not a concern for me, although bidirectional iterators are (and to a lesser extent, forward iterators).

Answer (score 5):

In this case, you aren't iterating over the contents of the container.  Instead, you are iterating over the valid iterators of the container.

So one approach would be to make that explicit.

Create a sequence of said iterators, with an `end` element that is one-past-the-`end` of the one-past-the-last iterator of the sequence.

Because I'm insane, if I had to solve this, I'd write a function `iterators`, which, when given a `sequence` (an object that `for( : )` loops work on), produces a `sequence` of iterators instead of a sequence of the underlying type.

It would take an `enum` argument that says if it is inclusive-of-the-`end` iterator.  It would default to exclusive.

You'd use it like this:

```
for( auto it : iterators( sequence, include_end ) ) {
  // code
}
```

the work to write that function wouldn't be trivial, but it would make the loop at point of use look really clean.

Writing this in a sane way would involve using the `boost` iterator library.  Slightly less sane would involve reimplementing a piece of the `boost` iterator library, either verbatim or by writing it worse by hand, then using that.  Writing it without copying the spirit or text of `boost` would be a bad idea.

```
template<typename iterator>
struct iterator_iterator: boost::iterator_facade<
  iterator_iterator<iterator>, iterator,
  typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::iterator_category,
  iterator const&,
  typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::difference_type
>:{
  // sufficient state:
  iterator current;
  iterator src_end;
  bool past_end_iterator;
  // now, implement the core operations.  Note that
  // random advance has to be careful, because we cannot advance
  // current beyond src_end.  Note we should implement every one
  // of the methods in the requirements (including advance), but
  // only the ones that the underlying iterator's category requires
  // should be called and hence instantiated.
  iterator dereference() const { return current; }
  bool equal( iterator_iterator<iterator> other ) const {
    if (past_end_iterator || other.past_end_iterator)
      return past_end_iterator && other.past_end_iterator;
    return current == other.current;
  }
  void increment() {
    if (current == src_end) {
      past_end_iterator = true;
    } else {
      ++current;
    }
  }
  void decrement() {
    if (past_end_iterator) {
      past_end_iterator = false;
    } else {
      --current;
    }
  }
  void advance( std::ptrdiff_t n ) {
    if (n==0)
      return;
    if (n==1) {
      increment();
    } else if (n==-1) {
      decrement();
    }
    if ((n>0) && ( current+(n-1) == src_end ) {
      current = src_end;
      past_end_iterator = true;
    } else if ((n<0) && past_end_iterator) {
      past_end_iterator = false;
      ++n;
      current = src_end + n;
    } else {
      current += n;
    }
  }
  typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::difference_type distance_to(
    iterator_iterator<iterator> other
  ) const {
    if (past_end_iterator || other.past_end_iterator) {
      if (past_end_iterator && other.past_end_iterator) {
        return 0;
      using std::distance;
      auto retval = distance( current, other.current );
      if (past_end_iterator)
        return retval-1;
      else
        return retval+1;
    }
  }
};
```

or something like that.  (not compiled, just written)  You'd take your pair of begin/end iterators, and either create a pair of begin/end iterator iterators, or a begin/past end iterator iterator, depending on if you want to include the end iterator in your iteration of the iterators.

I suspect the CRTP above is among the highest density of useful use of the word iterator in stack overflow code: 13 uses of iterator in 5 lines of code.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question and making the code more readable at the same time.

Comment: @Mehrdad more readable at point of use -- but that is a lot of boilerplate to make it happen!

Comment: Yup that's why I haven't quite yet gone this route haha.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to execute the loop for `end`, even if it's equal to `begin`, your loop always executes at least once.

That being the case, it's probably easiest to write it as a `do`/`while` loop, so it only tests the condition *after* executing the loop body:

```
bool continuing;
i = begin;
do { 
    whatever();
} while ((continuing = (i != end)) && (++i, continuing));
```

The ugly terminating condition tests the *current* value of the iterator against end, then increments the iterator for the next iteration if (and only if) another iteration needs to be executed (then uses the value from the original comparison to continue/break the loop).

Comment: There are implementations that detect the problem, when using debug iterators.

Comment: What @R.MartinhoFernandes said.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I believe (at the expense of a bit of ugliness) that's corrected.

Comment: +1 yup thanks. I think I finally found a better solution too, I'll post it in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

There's some chat about this issue in [Visual Studio 2010 (C++): suppress C4706 warning temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986018/visual-studio-2010-c-suppress-c4706-warning-temporarily)

You might try using `!!` to hint that you intend to treat the `(finished = !finished)` as a boolean (It's two `!` unaries in sequence, and converts 0 to 0 and everything else to 1):

```
bool finished = false;
for (Iterator i = begin; i != end || !! (finished = !finished) ; finished ? i : ++i)
{
    // (body)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on Visual C++ 2013 unfortunately, not sure about other versions. :(

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found a solution myself...

```
for (Iter i = items.begin();
          i != items.end() || (finished = !finished, finished);
          finished ? i : ++i, ++offset)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that's acceptable to you, but man I hope nobody else ever has to maintain that code. :)

Comment: pretty much all the other answers here are better than this one